# How to execute a "Channel to Selection" in Gimp python-fu?

Tags: python, gimpfu, python-fu

I want to convert custom channels into selection using python-fu. This can be done manually in Gimp using "Channel to Selection".

I can retrieve the image and the channel as Python objects but I can’t figure out how to convert this channel to selection.

```py
images = gimp.image_list()

image = images[0]

ch = image.channels[0]

# ?
```

What I’m missing here is how do a selection from a channel.

Answer (score 4):

After some digging, I finally found the answer:

```py
images = gimp.image_list()

image = images[0]

ch = image.channels[0]

pdb.gimp_image_select_item(image, 2, ch)
```

More info about the second argument in the `gimp-image-select-item` documentation I quote here:

> The desired operation with current selection { CHANNEL-OP-ADD (0), CHANNEL-OP-SUBTRACT (1), CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE (2), CHANNEL-OP-INTERSECT (3) }

I have the impression the official Python module miss a `gimp.Image.select_item(item, operation` method. In my case it would give:

```py
image.select_item(ch, 'replace')
```

Comment: `gimp_image_select_item` works in Python too.